# What is the difference between spring parent context and child context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was reading spring doc the core container I want to understand the purpose of **ref parent** when inject collaborators then I found this notion of parent context child context or parent container and current container this is the part that I'm confuse about it : 
[This part of doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-ref-element)

> Specifying the target bean through the parent attribute creates a
>   reference to a bean that is in a parent container of the current
>   container. The value of the parent attribute may be the same as either
>   the id attribute of the target bean, or one of the values in the name
>   attribute of the target bean, and the target bean must be in a parent
>   container of the current one. You use this bean reference variant
>   mainly when you have a hierarchy of containers and you want to wrap an
>   existing bean in a parent container with a proxy that will have the
>   same name as the parent bean.

```
<!-- in the parent context -->
<bean id="accountService" class="com.foo.SimpleAccountService">
    <!-- insert dependencies as required as here -->
</bean>
<!-- in the child (descendant) context -->
<bean id="accountService" <!-- bean name is the same as the parent bean -->
    class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target">
        <ref parent="accountService"/> <!-- notice how we refer to the parent bean -->
    </property>
    <!-- insert other configuration and dependencies as required here -->
</bean>
```

can someone give me some help or an example of this two type of context ? and what is the purpose of the **ref parent**  Thank you in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The beans of the Spring run inside an application context.

> The Application Context is Spring's advanced container. Similar to
>   BeanFactory, it can load bean definitions, wire beans together, and
>   dispense beans upon request. Additionally, it adds more
>   enterprise-specific functionality such as the ability to resolve
>   textual messages from a properties file and the ability to publish
>   application events to interested event listeners. This container is
>   defined by org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext interface.
>   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_applicationcontext_container.htm

For each application context you can have many configuration files, configuration classes or a mix of both.

You can create an application context with a code like this:

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
```

And obtain the beans with `context.getBean` or with `@autowired`.

There are some cases when you want(or need) to have a context hierarchy. In these cases Spring provides a way of specifying a parent context. If you look at this constructor, you will see that it receives a context parent.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html#FileSystemXmlApplicationContext-org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext-

As you can see the parent context is the same type of a child context, they both are http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html.

The difference is that they are related through a parent/child relationship. Not a compose(import) relationship.

The most common case where you see this is in a Spring MVC application, this applications have 2 context, the first is the dispatcher servlet context and the other one is the root context. 
Here you can see the relationship
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet

And here you can see an example of application context hierarchy in spring boot applications.

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-and-application-context-hierarchy

Comment: Well explained as you said spring mvc is a best example ,Thank you

Comment: I thought the DispatcherServlet is the first entry point for booting up the Spring framework in servlet/web containers viz. Tomcat etc., So I wonder where the "root" application context is defined and how it's boot up...