# How to properly integrate Vaadin with Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I'm having some trouble integrating Vaadin with my Spring application. I have all my beans in the "rootcontext.xml" file. I can call the beans by instantiating the "rootcontext.xml" then calling the bean for one of my service classes.

I can populate the table this way but is this the right way of calling the service class? Because I have more tables that have to call this.

```
public final class TestTable extends Table {

private ApplicationContext applicationContext = (ApplicationContext) VaadinServlet.getCurrent().getServletContext()
        .getAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE);

private Service service = this.applicationContext.getBean("service",
        Service.class);

public TestTable() {
    service.findAll()
}
```

Here is my UI class:

```
@SpringUI
@Theme("dashboard")
@Widgetset("vaadin.DashboardWidgetSet")
public class TestUI extends UI {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -620721219079395670L;

private final DashboardEventBus dashboardEventbus = new DashboardEventBus();

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

    setLocale(Locale.US);

    DashboardEventBus.register(this);
    Responsive.makeResponsive(this);
    addStyleName(ValoTheme.UI_WITH_MENU);

    updateContent();

    // Some views need to be aware of browser resize events so a
    // BrowserResizeEvent gets fired to the event bus on every occasion.
    Page.getCurrent().addBrowserWindowResizeListener(new BrowserWindowResizeListener() {
        @Override
        public void browserWindowResized(final BrowserWindowResizeEvent event) {
            DashboardEventBus.post(new BrowserResizeEvent());
        }
    });
}

private void updateContent() {
    setContent(new MainView());
}

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/TestUI/*", "/VAADIN/*" }, name = "TestUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = TestUI.class, productionMode = false)
public static class TestUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {

}
}
```

My root-context.xml file is in the directory /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml.

The applicationContext.xml for the Vaadin servlet is in the directory /WEB-INF/spring/vaadin/applicationContext.xml.

And here is my web.xml. The Vaadin Spring tutorial says to use the context loader to initialize 'applicationContext.xml'. I could add its path to the contextConfigLocation param but there should only be one root context.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

Vaadin Configuration class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.EnableVaadin;

@Configuration
@EnableVaadin
public class VaadinConfiguration {

@Autowired
private Service service;

@Bean
public UI ui() {
    System.out.println(service.findAll().size());

    TestUI testUI = new TestUI();

    testUI.setService(service);

    return testUI;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you get the chance to go over the newer [Vaadin-spring tutorial](http://vaadin.github.io/spring-tutorial/) or the older [wiki section](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Spring+Vaadin/I+-+Getting+Started+with+Vaadin+Spring+and+Spring+Boot)? To keep it clean the table should just display data, _someone_ else should call the service and provide (populate) the information to the table

Comment: @Morfic Hey thanks for the response. I did go through the tutorial. If I already had a rootcontext.xml, do i still need to create an applicationContext.xml like the tutorial says?

Comment: Any spring or vaadin experts out there?

Comment: `applicationContext.xml` is a common name used for XML-defined spring context, but you can name it whatever you want, so no, if you already have your `rootcontext.xml` you don't need to create the other one. One thing you could try, is to migrate to annotation based contexts. By no means that's necessary and it's a personal preference, but I find it more helpful to view info while writing my code than having to go to the XML definition, even if nowadays IDEs have good spring support for such things.

Comment: @Morfic I would like to separate the configuration. Use the root-context.xml as my datasource configurations and have my vaadin configuration in its own xml. But when I try to autowire the service classes from the root I just keep getting null pointer exceptions.

Comment: From your comment I assume you're instantiating 2 different spring contexts. Usually there's one such context that contains all the bean definitions so it can inject them properly when required (unless you need a [hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452644/what-is-the-difference-between-spring-parent-context-and-child-context)). With 2 distinct contexts, one won't know about what's in the other. What you could do, is to [split it into smaller parts and import them in your root context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600095/splitting-applicationcontext-to-multiple-files).

Comment: @Morfic I appreciate the help. In my configuration class which is use Java based configuration like the Vaadin spring tutorial. If I autowire one of my service classes from the root context and create a bean inside of the configuration class it works. I do a system out and I see a value. But when I actually inject it and do the system out from the created bean I get a null pointer exception. It's really frustrating.

Comment: @Morfic I updated the question to show my configuration class. Thanks again for the help

Comment: Leave it as it is, with `root-context` referenced in `web.xml`, and import your `applicationContext` in your `root-context` as described in the [previous link about splitting a context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600095/splitting-applicationcontext-to-multiple-files). If I were you, I'd fully migrate to an annotation-based context (you already have a few such beans and configs), and not worry about XMLs any more. Spring boot or not it's up to you, and the [vaadin tutorial](http://vaadin.github.io/spring-tutorial) should offer sufficient info about how to bootstrap it and use it.

Comment: You can also get some inspiration from their simple [vaadin-spring integration demo app](https://github.com/vaadin/spring-tutorial), based on spring boot.

Comment: @Morfic OK, I think that's the annotation based is the route I'll go. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues I realized was that I was using the wrong version for Vaadin Spring. I was using Vaadin Spring 2.0 but it doesn't work with Vaadin 7. So I switched it to 1.2.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I moved the Spring Vaadin Servlet configuration to my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UIServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.spring.server.SpringVaadinServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UIServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UI/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UIServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I also had to add some Vaadin Spring annotations to the configuration class and UI class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableVaadin
@EnableVaadinNavigation
public class VaadinConfiguration {

}
```

@EnableVaadinNavigation is needed to enable Navigation for Spring Views.

```
@SpringUI
@Theme("dashboard")
public class UI extends UI {

@Autowired
private SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

private final HorizontalLayout root = new HorizontalLayout();
private ComponentContainer content;
private Navigator navigator;

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

    setLocale(Locale.US);

    Responsive.makeResponsive(this);
    addStyleName(ValoTheme.UI_WITH_MENU);

    root.setSizeFull();
    root.addStyleName("mainview");
    setContent(root);

    root.addComponent(new DashboardMenu());

    content = new CssLayout();
    content.addStyleName("view-content");
    content.setSizeFull();
    root.addComponent(content);
    root.setExpandRatio(content, 1.0f);

    navigator = new Navigator(this, content);
    navigator.addProvider(viewProvider);
    navigator.navigateTo(DashboardView.NAME);
}
}
```

I autowired SpringViewProvider in the UI which is also needed to recognize your classes that are annotated with Spring View.

All the configuration can be found here:

https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Spring+Vaadin/I+-+Getting+Started+with+Vaadin+Spring+and+Spring+Boot